# Do healing bonuses (Pacifist healer) apply to flat healing effects like consecrated ground?

Tags: dnd-4e

Do the healing bonuses from feats like Pacifist Healer apply to flat, repeating healing effects like consecrated ground?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the feat; you need to read the wording carefully. Pacifist Healer says "When you use a divine power that allows a target to spend a healing surge..." Since Consecrated Ground has no target and the people affected don't spend surges, Pacifist Healer does not apply.

At this point, most healing-boost feats and magic items trigger only when someone spends a healing surge. Healer's Implement is another example: "When you let a creature spend a healing surge..." The notable exceptions are a) Healer's Brooch, which is a neck item: "Property: When you use a power that enables you or an ally to regain hit points, add the brooch's enhancement bonus to the hit points gained" and b) Beacon of Hope (level 1 daily): "your healing powers restore +5 hit points until the end of the encounter."

My strict interpretation would be that Healer's Brooch would not work, since the property triggers when you use the power. You use Consecrated Ground once; the effect triggers later, after the power is used. Beacon of Hope, conversely, would work with Consecrated Ground, since it's a flat bonus to the hit points your healing powers restore.

I do not have a WotC FAQ reference for this, but general consensus on the WotC boards agrees with me. FWIW, the [Character Optimizer board cleric handbook](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19648946/Holy_Smoke!_A_Clerics_Handbook&post_num=5#334474434) claims, in reference to Beacon of Hope, that "Post errata the effects bonus healing still works for later powers like consecrated ground and spirit of life."

Obviously table rulings take priority. I wouldn't be at all shocked if a GM ruled that Healer's Brooch would work with Consecrated Ground, in particular -- my opinion there is pretty Talmudic, since it relies on a definition of when you use a power.

None of these bonuses apply to granted regeneration, btw, since regeneration is a property belonging to whoever's regenerating -- you're granting regeneration to someone, you're not granting hit points. See also [the official FAQ.](http://wizards.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/wizards.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=1396) But Consecrated Ground is not regeneration.